# ST-901 GPSS Converter diagrams

Tags: flight-controls, general-aviation, autopilot

I'm looking for pin-out diagrams for the S-Tec ST-901 GPSS Converter.   This unit will go between a Garmin GPS400W GPS Navigator and an S-Tec 50 autopilot.